# create an xpath for below code which is inside one div

Tags: xpath

ned to create xpath for

```
<div id="sampleDiv" style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; height: 289px;">
<table style="width:100%; border:0; text-align:left;" class="tableattributes" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">



<!-- PRS on TIS - Start -->

<!-- PRS on TIS - End -->




    <!-- PRS on TIS - Start -->
    <!-- Modified the Code to pass Status as an argument to makeHightlight method -->




            <tbody><tr style="background: rgb(246, 246, 204);" onclick="makeHightlight(this,'000290366','Received')" ondblclick="showDetails('onDetail')">


    <!-- PRS on TIS - End -->


     <!--  Release 15.1 Enhancement T300018844 End  -->
        <td style="width:10%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal">000290366</label></td>
        <td style="width:11%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal"></label></td>
        <td style="width:12%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal"></label></td>
        <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal">200850</label></td> 
        <td style="width:9%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal">Received</label></td>
        <td style="width:10%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal">11/11/2017</label></td>
        <td style="width:10%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal">10/27/2017</label></td>
        <td style="width:10%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal"></label></td>
        <td style="width:11%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal">1Z5F0F059090032501</label></td>
        <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><label class="normal">UPS</label></td>
        <td style="width:1;">&nbsp;</td>

  </tr>  



</tbody></table>
</div>
```

tried :

```
//*[contains(@label,'Received')]"
```

and

```
//*[contains(text(),'Received')]"
```

Comment: Please make your question a question rather than a bunch of statements. Explain what you are trying to do, and where you are struggling.

Comment: i am trying to select the element from xpath. i gave

Comment: Hi fed,
i am trying  to check for the presence of the Received label in the td[5] by creating the xpath..//*[contains(text()'Received')]"this does not work.....but the similar xpath for text ' UPS' in td[10] [contains(text(),'UPS')

Comment: //*[@id="sampleDiv"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/label : xpath of received
//*[@id="sampleDiv"]/table/tbody/tr/td[10]/label:xpath for UPS

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Xpath, you will get **Recieved** text as what you are looking for

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[5]/label
```